# Is it true or false? if $E(X)\geq E(Y)$ then $X\geq Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm not pretty sure if this is true. We already know that if $X\leq Y$ then $E(X)\leq E(Y)$. But it would be great if someone can show me a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false, here is a counterexample: let $(S,\mathbb{P}) = ([0,1],\lambda)$ and consider $X = \chi_{[0,2^{-1}]}$, $Y = \chi_{[2^{-1},1]}$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X) \ge \mathbb{E}(Y)$, but $X(\omega) < Y(\omega)$ for $\omega \in (2^{-1},1]$.

Answer (score 4):

False. Let $X$ be the amount of money you spend on a lottery ticket and $Y$ be the amount you win. $E(X) > E(Y)$, but it's possible to win more than you spent.

Comment: Proof without abstraction, nice !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can show that:

> If $X< Y $ almost surely, then $\forall \omega\in\Omega :X(\omega)< Y(\omega)$
>
> So: $\mathsf E(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\operatorname{d} P \;<\; \int_\Omega Y(\omega)\operatorname d P = \mathsf E(Y)$
>
> Ergo: $X < Y \text{ a.s.}\implies \mathsf E(X)< \mathsf E(Y)$

---

***However***   We cannot say the converse, because the contrapositive is: $$\mathsf E(X)\geq \mathsf E(Y) \implies X\geq Y \text{ sometimes}$$

That is *not* the result we want.   The ordering of the expectation does *not* guarantee that the variables *will* be ordered, almost surely, only that that ordering occurs for some outcomes.

**For example:** Let $Y$ be the result of a standard cube dice (a d6).  Let $X$ be the result of a standard octahedral dice (a d8), tossed at the same time.  Then $\mathsf E(X)=4.5, \mathsf E(X)=4.5$, but sometimes $X<Y, X=Y,$ or $X>Y$ are all possible (they are non-zero measure events).

$$\mathsf E(X)\geq \mathsf E(Y) \quad\nRightarrow\quad X\geq Y\text{ a.s.}$$